# Displaying percentages next to HTML5 slider values

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I have 6 sliders, each with a respective value from 0-100. I'd love to be able to show each slider percentage (against the total slider sum) to the right of each slider, but I am not sure how to do that.

I am able to grab the slider value to display above, as well as the slider values and sum of the values as JavaScript variables, but I'm not able to...

1) update the percentage values as the sliders are moved (I think I might need to write a separate function that does this, and then call it right after the slider values are displayed?) or

2) display the percentage values (which I rounded to a whole number effectively) just to the right after where the slider value is.

Can anyone clue me in on how to do this? It shouldn't be difficult from a technical standpoint but I have little experience in this arena. I am not using jquery either (as you can tell)... Thanks!

Code: 
http://jsbin.com/owIjEXA/7/edit

```
<!-- Put divs here... trying to set up the display of percentages -->
<div id="val_weight1"></div>
<div id="val_weight2"></div>
<div id="val_weight3"></div>
<div id="val_weight4"></div>
<div id="val_weight5"></div>
<div id="val_weight6"></div>

<!-- form start -->
<form name = "form_weight1" id = "form_weight1" >
  <text><b> First Weight </b></text>
  <input id="weight1" input type="range" name="weight1" min="0" max="100" value="40" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">40</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>

  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Original JS bin that modified code: http://jsbin.com/ISekuSiN/5/edit  -->
    function get_nextsibling(n) {
      x=n.nextSibling;
      while (x.nodeType!=1) {
        x=x.nextSibling; }
      return x; }

    function showValue(self) {
      get_nextsibling(self).innerHTML=self.value; }
  </script>
</form>

<form name = "form_weight2" id = "form_weight2" >
  <text><b> Second Weight </b></text>
  <input id="weight2" input type="range" name="weight2" min="0" max="100" value="10" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">10</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>
</form>

<form name = "form_weight3" id = "form_weight3" >
  <text><b> Third Weight</b></text>
  <input id="weight3" input type="range" name="weight3" min="0" max="100" value="20" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">20</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>
</form>

<form name = "form_weight4" id = "form_weight4" >
  <text><b> Fourth Weight </b></text> 
  <input id="weight4" input type="range" name="weight4" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">5</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>
</form>

<form name = "form_weight5" id = "form_weight5" >
  <text><b> Fifth Weight </b></text>
  <input id="weight5" input type="range" name="weight5" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">5</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>
</form>

<form name = "form_weight6" id = "form_weight6" >
  <text><b> Sixth Weight </b></text>
  <input id="weight6" input type="range" name="weight6" min="0" max="100" value="20" step="1" onchange="showValue(this); " />
  <span id="range">20</span>
  <text>/ PERCENTAGE%</text>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var weightfactor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight1").value) ;
  var weightfactor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight2").value) ;
  var weightfactor3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight3").value) ;
  var weightfactor4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight4").value) ;
  var weightfactor5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight5").value) ;
  var weightfactor6 = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight6").value) ;

  var weight_factor_sum = weightfactor1 + weightfactor2 + weightfactor3 + weightfactor4 + weightfactor5 + weightfactor6 ;

    document.getElementById('val_weight1').innerHTML = (weightfactor1 / weight_factor_sum)*100;

    document.getElementById('val_weight2').innerHTML = (weightfactor2 / weight_factor_sum)*100;

    document.getElementById('val_weight3').innerHTML = (weightfactor3 / weight_factor_sum)*100;

    document.getElementById('val_weight4').innerHTML = (weightfactor4 / weight_factor_sum)*100;

    document.getElementById('val_weight5').innerHTML = (weightfactor5 / weight_factor_sum)*100;  

  document.getElementById('val_weight6').innerHTML = (weightfactor6 / weight_factor_sum)*100;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
document.querySelector("#range").addEventListener("change", function(e){
    document.querySelector(".range").textContent=e.currentTarget.value;
})
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw78m/) to play with.

When dealing with several sliders, it doesn't make sense to add a `change` event for each of the sliders, instead use `event-delegation` (you attach the `change`-listener to the parent element containing all sliders and dispatch the event yourself).

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw78m/2/) dealing with more sliders an a sum field.